# PHP - Trouble sending e-mail with attachment from form

Tags: php, email, file-upload, encoding

I having some trouble sending e-mail with attachment from the php MAIL function. The error checking is working but I can't get the file to upload and send in the e-mail. I'm using code I've pulled off the net. Just can't seem to get it working. Anyone have any thoughts? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! URL to follow:

http://www.xsp.com/careers2.php

```
if(array_key_exists('submit_check', $_POST)) {
                        if($_POST['first_name'] != NULL && $_POST['last_name'] != NULL && $_POST['e-mail'] != NULL && $_POST['address'] != NULL && $_POST['city'] != NULL && $_POST['zipcode'] != NULL && $_POST['country'] != NULL && $_POST['telephone'] != NULL && $_POST['first_name'] != '' && $_POST['last_name'] != '' && $_POST['e-mail'] != '' && $_POST['address'] != '' && $_POST['city'] != '' && $_POST['zipcode'] != '' && $_POST['country'] != '' || 
        (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/doc") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000) {                         
                            $first_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s', '', $_POST['first_name']);
                            $last_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s', '', $_POST['last_name']);
                            $city = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s', '', $_POST['city']);
                            $state = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s', '', $_POST['state']);
                            $zipcode = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s', '', $_POST['zipcode']);
                            $email = $_POST['e-mail'];

                            // we'll begin by assigning the To address and message subject
                            $to = "myhiddenemailaddress@domain.com";

                            $subject = $form_title;

                           // get the sender's name and email address
                           // we'll just plug them a variable to be used later
                           //$from = stripslashes($_POST['fromname'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['fromemail']).">";
                           $form = $email;

                           // generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
                           $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

                           // store the file information to variables for easier access
                           $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                           $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                           $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                           $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

                           // here we'll hard code a text message
                           // again, in reality, you'll normally get this from the form submission
                           $message = "Here is your file: $name";

                           /*echo $message."<br />";
                           echo "TMP NAME:".$tmp_name."<br />";
                           echo $_FILES['file'];*/

                           // if the upload succeded, the file will exist
                           if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

                              // check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
                              if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

                                 // open the file for a binary read
                                 $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

                                 // read the file content into a variable
                                 $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

                                 // close the file
                                 fclose($file);

                                // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
                                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                             }

                             // now we'll build the message headers
                              $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
                                 "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
                                 "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
                                 " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

                              // next, we'll build the message body
                              // note that we insert two dashes in front of the
                              // MIME boundary when we use it
                              $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                                 "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                                 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                                 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                                 $message . "\n\n";
                                $message .="Application Form \n";
                                $message .="First Name: ".$first_name."\n";
                                $message .="Last Name: ".$last_name."\n";
                                $message .="E-Mail: ".$email."\n";

                                if ($_POST["company"] != NULL && $_POST["company"] != "") {
                                    $company = $_POST["company"];
                                    $message .= "COMPANY: ".$company."\n";
                                }

                                if ($_POST["position"] != NULL && $_POST["position"] != "") {
                                    $position = $_POST["position"];
                                    $message .= "POSITION: ".$position."\n";
                                }

                                if ($_POST["address"] != NULL && $_POST["address"] != "") {
                                    $address = $_POST["address"];
                                    $message .= "ADDRESS: ".$address."\n";
                                }

                                if ($city != NULL && $city != "") {
                                    $message .= "CITY: ".$city."\n";
                                }

                                if ($state != NULL && $state != "") {
                                    $message .= "STATE: ".$state."\n";
                                }

                                if ($zipcode != NULL && $zipcode != "") {
                                    $message .= "ZIPCODE: ".$zipcode."\n";
                                }

                                if ($_POST["telephone"] != NULL && $_POST["telephone"] != "") {
                                    $telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
                                    $message .= "TELEPHONE: ".$telephone."\n";
                                }

                                if ($_POST["website"] != NULL && $_POST["website"] != "") {
                                    $website = $_POST["website"];
                                    $message .= "WEBSITE: ".$website."\n\n";
                                }

                                if ($_POST["message"] != NULL && $_POST["message"] != "") {
                                    $message_text = $_POST["message"];
                                    $message .= "MESSAGE TEXT: ".$message_text."\n\n";
                                }


                              // now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment
                              // we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as
                              // an attachment, then add the file content and set another boundary to
                              // indicate that the end of the file has been reached
                              $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                                 "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                                 " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                                 //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                                 //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                                 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                                 $data . "\n\n" .
                                 "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

                              // now we just send the message
                              if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
                                 echo "Message Sent";
                              else
                                 echo "Failed to send";
                           }
                        } else {
                            if ($file > 0) {
                                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                            }

                            echo '<p class="note" style="margin:5px 0 5px 0; color:#ff0000;">Please fill in all the required fields</p>';
                        }
                        //echo '<p class="note" style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">First Name: '.$first_name.'</p>';
                    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use PHPMAILER, its easy to use, a had a lot of examples (included a method to attach files)
[pagina de phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: I have too much proprietary code to work it into this framework sadly.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to remove the \r's and replace them with \n's. Most mailservers no longer accept \r
- You need random hash separators for the MIME (see below code for example)

  > $filename = "MyAttachment.pdf";
  >
  > $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
  >
  > $separator = md5(time());
  >
  > // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
  >
  > $eol =PHP_EOL;
  >
  > // main header
  >
  > $headers = "From: ".$from.$eol;
  >
  > $headers .=
  >   "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  >   boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
  >
  > // no more headers after this, we start the body! //
  >
  > $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
  >
  > $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:
  >   7bit".$eol.$eol;
  >
  > $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
  >
  > // message $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
  >
  > $body .= "Content-Type:
  >   text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
  >
  > $body .=
  >   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
  >
  > $body .= $message.$eol;
  >
  > // attachment
  >
  > $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
  >
  > $body .= "Content-Type:
  >   application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
  >
  > $body .=
  >   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
  >
  > $body .=
  >   "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
  >
  > $body .=
  >   $attachment.$eol;
  >
  > $body .= "--".$separator."--";
  >
  > // send message
  >
  > mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

or you can just download the 3 class files from PHPmailer as suggested above since it has all of this already finished for you.